# Nvidia Prime doesn't appear in Nvidia Settings on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime, 18.04

I saw a question over here, says that Nvidia Graphics jumps to 90º and fan goes at maximum speed.
So, I want to use the Intel graphics integrated, but in Nvidia Settings (I use Ubuntu 18.04, Nvidia driver 390) doesn't appear the option to use Intel graphics.
In Ubuntu 16.04 I don't know if it's the driver or what, but doesn't work this option (but appears in Nvidia Settings) because then Ubuntu doesn't allow go to your session. You try to enter but it returns to the gdm. Maybe in this version doesn't have this fail.

Comment: People here are [talking about this issues][1] 

Briefly, something is "wrong" with prime and new nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 18.04
Has to do with Ubuntu switching back to xorg and xorg 1.20 not being released in Jan as expected but delayed (in RC2 now) and the new drivers (nvidia 390) being designed for that 1.20.
I feel that prime is not working properly today on 18.04 at all.  

  [1]: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032482/linux/optimus-on-ubuntu-18-04-is-a-train-wreck-beyond-imagination-wondering-about-other-distributions/

Comment: @DanieleDellafiore The same drivers work perfectly on 17.10, afaik it has to do with the 4.15 kernel which has a new mechanism for gpu switching, but doesn't play nice with nvidia's proprietary drivers.

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe yes I also think that, I guess it's a matter of time everything will be alligned.

Comment: You're right @DanieleDellafiore the problem is in the kernel, far as I know, the devs thought that the Nvidia Prime is not useful, or at least not for them (or they don't want to give support to this).

Answer (score 0):

I saw the "fail". It's stupid but I didn't find the option until now.

We have to set in terminal `sudo apt install nvidia-prime` and then we'll have this option in Nvidia Settings.

Besides, I had to put in the GRUB settings `noveau.runpm=-1` to use the Intel graphics.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Ubuntu 18.04. (update but don’t upgrade it.)
2. Disable nouveau

   ```sh
   printf '%s\n' 'blacklist nouveau' 'options nouveau modeset=0' 'alias nouveau off' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   and reboot.
3. Download driver from Nvidia. (In my case it was version 390.48 which worked.)
4. Stop X Server:

   ```sh
   telinit 3
   ```
5. Execute your `.run` install with root privileges.
6. Reboot and test driver installation by typing

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
   glxinfo | grep version
   ```

   If you see Nvidia there along with version then…
7. Install `nvidia-prime`:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
   ```

   and reboot.
8. Finally you can see the switch in `nvidia-settings`. (But it is better to switch by command.)

   ```sh
   prime-select "nvidia" or "intel"
   ```

Comment: With this you're pretty sure that the Nvidia graphics doesn't work while Intel does? I see this problem in my laptop and over there ( https://github.com/stockmind/dell-xps-9560-ubuntu-respin/issues/8 )